# Windows virus removed .exe while allowed

Tags: windows, security, virus-removal, malware-removal, malware-detection

Windows 10 virus & threat removed a .exe file it thought was malware even though it was previously allowed.
When windows security found the .exe file it said it was a threat. I hit "allow" then, all of a sudden, it removed the file and it disappeared. I had allowed this file in the past and it was there for a long time. I even opened the folder containing it a bunch of times and when the same message popped up, I allowed it but today it removed it.
I can't find it anywhere. Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: `Is there a way to get it back?` - If it hasn't simply been quranteed you can restore it.  Within Windows Security what is the current status of the file? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting any commentary

Comment: That's the thing, it didn't get quarantined, it was completely removed and not under threat history.

Comment: Care to provide screenshots of what you see?  It would be odd that Windows Defender would find a threat, and not list that threat, allowing you to identify its a threat and ultimately permanently remove it

Comment: When I get back to my office I will post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows virus removed .exe while allowed.

According to your question, it does not appear to be in your WD quarantine.  Do check that of course.

My guess is that the file was not properly whitelisted and things then change with Windows Defender Updates. Possibly Windows Defender Updates may require whitelisting again, depending on the file.

Once removed, you need to get the file from a backup or from the original source. Otherwise it is gone.

Backups are always essential all the time.

Comment: Yeah, it ate my backup too.

Comment: So my answer applies - you need to get the file from the original source if available or otherwise it is gone.

Comment: It was on a USB key and windows removed it from that too when I went o load it. What about a restore point when it was allowed?

Comment: It appears to have been a very serious threat. Overall my answer above applies.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: Would activating TPM in the bios create this situation? Either it's a coincidence or activating TPM caused the issue. Not sure why, while security was asking what to do, it just removed it.

Comment: I have not seen TPM cause this. It appears to be a function of Windows Defender.  I have TPM enabled, Windows 11, and I have seen this happening as a result of Windows Defender.

Comment: "Would activating TPM in the bios create this situation?" - TPM and Windows Defender have absolutely nothing to do one another.

Comment: Right on. Thank you.